# Как открыть окно регулирования яркости на API 15?

Tags: java, android-intent, android

Вопрос такой: как открыть окно регулирования яркости (dialog?) на API 15? Т.е. не настройки дисплея, а именно яркости.

Аля это:

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего открыть окно регулировки не получится, но его можно создать самому.

Вот так можно считать значение яркости

```
try {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Bright: " + Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS));
} catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

А задать вот так:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, newValue);
LayoutParams layoutpars = getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutpars.screenBrightness = newValue / (float)255;
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutpars);
```

Думаю с созданием PopUp Activity и манипуляциями с SeekBar проблем не возникнет.

Ну и полезная ссылочка: http://android.programmerguru.com/how-to-change-screen-brightness-programmatically/

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю пример. Если что, напишу ещё.